# JSF call message bundle : EL in EL

Tags: jsf, properties, el

I am working in JSF2 and I have displayed a resource bundle to display messages from property files.

The configuration seems to be great (if I call `#{msg.risk}` "toto" is displayed)

messages.properties

```
...
COMPANYGROWTH=E249
RISK=TOTO
```

I would like to do this kind of thing :

View

```
<f:loadBundle basename="toto" var="msg"/>
...
<p:column>
    <h:outputText value="#{msg.#{key}}" />
</p:column>
```

Putting an EL in an EL like `#{msg.#{key}}` where `key` would be a declared row value in a datatable. Is there a way to do it ?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For that you should be using the brace notation `#{bean[property]}`.

Thus, so:

```
<h:outputText value="#{msg[key]}" />
```

Note that nesting EL expressions is always invalid syntax. You should see `#{...}` as one big evaluation space where variables interact with each other. You should not see `#{...}` as a single variable.

#### See also:

- [Our EL wiki page](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/el/info)